# How do I get data from 2 objects linked with pointer in 1 request [parse] [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nosql

Now I have 2 objects call Trip and User thats have a field call user point to User. I would like to show all trip detail and specify who are created.

I do something like:

```
    var teamQuery = PFUser.query()
    teamQuery.includeKey("username")

    var innerQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Trip")
    teamQuery.whereKey("user" , matchesQuery: innerQuery)

    innerQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

        var i1 = 0
        if !(error != nil){
            for object in objects{

                let sweet:PFObject = object as PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(sweet)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }
```

but I still got only data from Trip.